# Convert string into variable name in order to access properties

Tags: c#

I have several custom objects named student1...studentn. I want to use a for loop to write to console the properties of each custom object. Is this possible in C#? I have gathered that using dictionaries or reflection has worked, but I can't find a similar case to what I require. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            studentinfo student1 = new studentinfo("fname1", "sname1");
            studentinfo student2 = new studentinfo("fname2", "sname2");
            studentinfo student3 = new studentinfo("fname3", "sname3");

            studentinfo[] studentarray = new studentinfo[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student {} name: {} {}", i, studentarray[i].FirstName, studentarray[i].SurName);
            }
        }
        private class studentinfo
        {
            private string fName;
            private string sName;

            public studentinfo(string fName, string sName)
            {
                this.fName = fName;
                this.sName = sName;
            }
            public string FirstName
            {
                get { return this.fName; }
                set { if (value != null) { this.fName = value; } }
            }
            public string SurName
            {
                get { return this.sName; }
                set { if (value != null) { this.sName = value; } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"Student {i} name: {studentarray[i].FirstName} {studentarray[i].SurName}");` . Also your current code in the question will not compile.

Comment: "I have several custom objects named student1...studentn" - that's not what you've shown in the code. Do you *actually* have a bunch of separate variables, or do you have an array? If you don't have an array, is there any reason why you don't? It would be much easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than pseudocode.

Comment: I added 3 student variables to show what the custom object looks like. they are not in an array, however I was thinking of putting them in an array using the for loop with studenetarray[i] = studentdict[i] however this line is my problem, it gives me `cannot implicitly convert type string to 'name of namespace.class.customobj`

Comment: Yes, you should put them in an array. But it's not clear why you have a dictionary at all - and if you *do* have a dictionary, surely it should be a `DIctionary<int, StudentInfo>`. Where does the string come in? I suggest you take a step back and think more about what you really want. Also, *please* take the advice about providing a [mcve] - your current pseudo-code is clearly not what you're using given that the casing is wrong all over the place.

Comment: If you are coming from a world of dynamic scripting languages like for instance lua, I get why this is confusing. The answer is no, you cannot refer to a variable by its string name like this in C#.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. This is the reason arrays were invented. _USE AN ARRAY_ and the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The only way I can think of is to add each student object into the array manually, like: `studentarray[0] = student1`. What if I have a lot of student objects? I don't know how to add them using a loop. That is why I was under the impression that using a dictionary would work, but I guess that's not the right direction either.

Comment: The question is why don't you use an array in the first place? `studentarray[0] = new studentnfo("fname1", "sname1");`

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what they meant by using array now. Thanks for the tip. Out of curiosity, there is no way to change a variable name dynamically from a string in C#, just like Fortia mentioned?

Comment: Please rename your class to at least say "Info" and not "nfo"... Its one character longer but a hell of a lot clearer and a much better habit to have